# How to make semantic-release with CircleCI fail on no changes found

Tags: node.js, circleci, semantic-release

I have setup a CircleCI job to run semantic-release, but I would like CircleCI to fail when no changes are found. i.e. when semantic-release outputs:

> There are no relevant changes, so no new version is released

CircleCi snippet for the runline.

```
  - run:
      name: Semantic Release
      command: npm run semantic-release
```

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I haven't tested this and I don't know Node.js well in order to quickly test but here's my suggestion.

`grep` returns an exit code of `0` if it finds something and `1` if it doesn't. Any exit code other than `0` means a failure to CircleCI. Grep's `-q` flag means quiet, don't output text and the `&&` means only run if the previous command passes. So, this might work for you:

```
  - run:
      name: Semantic Release
      # Fail if there are no changes
      command: npm run semantic-release | grep -q "There are no relevant changes, so no new version is released." && exit 1
```

Again, I haven't personally tested it so I don't know how `semantic-release` outputs things but this might work.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is [intentionally not supported by semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/1331#issuecomment-545037195), however, if you need your pipelines to fail if no release will be created, you can either search for that specific text as suggested, or you can use a plugin to do this.

```sh
npm install --save-dev commit-analyzer-fail-on-no-release
```

In your semantic-release configuration file, replace the default commit analyzer with `commit-analyzer-fail-on-no-release`. All configuration options pass through to the default plugin if you have configured `@semantic-release/commit-analyzer`.

**`.releaserc`**

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "commit-analyzer-fail-on-no-release"
   ]
 }
```

[Learn more about this plugin](https://github.com/evelynhathaway/commit-analyzer-fail-on-no-release)

Answer (score 0):

semantic-release does not errors out in the case of no release on purpose.

If you add a commit that doesn't warrant a release (for example a commit that modify a comment in the code or the code formatting) you don't want your CI to fail.

In short, no making a release when no release is needed is a not an error case, therefore the CI should not errors out.